# Can't find Georgian QWERTY on my clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I need to install Georgian QWERTY input source for keyboard but I can't find it in the settings. There are other versions like Georgian (Italy), Georgian(Mess) but no Georgian(QWERTY) which is what I need and what everybody uses here.

I also tried this https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en but no luck.

Comment: Isn't the basic _Georgian_ keyboard layout really a QWERTY one?